# Updating Value on ObservableCollection object change

Tags: c#, wpf, notifications, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection` containing names and averages.

Then i have a textblock wich uses a converter to get an average on those averages from the collection above

the idea is to have something like:

```
Name1  2.15 %
Name2  1.24 %
Name3  3.25 %


       2.21 %
```

The list of names and averages is on a listbox and comes from the collection, the average on the averages below is on a textblock binded to the same collection via a converter that averages the values out.

All this is working properly. Now, the average values in the listbox are in a textbox and can be edited, but when they are edited, the average of the averages doesn't get updated because only the property within the object sends the property changed notification, not the collection itself.

Is there a way to tell the value below to update itself when the value of the average on any of the lines gets changed?

Comment: Why don't you post some of your supporting code?  It's a lot easier to point you in the right direction that way

Comment: @DavidL - Well it seemed pointless given the question beeing is there a way to make an object's property change lead to the collection it is in being reported as changed. It's about knowing if there's a way to notify things up the ladder so to speak. Propagate the notification on a property up to it's object and from it up to the collection that holds it. Do you have any particular part of the code in mind that might be relevant to this?

Comment: @537mfb In support to David L's comment, it is easier to be helpful if we have class and property names to work with.

Comment: @JefferyKhan - that is true to most cases - but in this case i don't see it. It was a question on how to notify changes up the ladder, not about my code won't work as expected, what did i do wrong

Comment: @537mfb You're absolutely right based on your question, but it would have made my answer a lot easier to come up with below if you had :)

Comment: @JefferyKhan - My working solution gets things a bit complicated with collections within collections - would just be messed up to anyone figure out all it's intricasies - this was actually easier - trust me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend changing you're design.

Create a property on your ViewModel which represents the average of your collection, and bind your textbox to that new property.

For instance...

Place in get method:

```
    //Get my objects and subscribe to their property change event
    MyObjects = GetMyObjects();
    foreach (var item in MyObjects)
    {
        item.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.PropertyName == "Value")
                {
                    Average = MyObjects.Average(x.Value);
                }
            };
    }
```

And here is your new viewmodel property:

```
    //Bind your textbox to this guy
    double _Average;
    public double Average
    {
        get { return _Average; }
        set
        {
            if (_Average != value)
            {
                _Average = value;
                OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Average");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Interesting - Close to something i had tried but adds just enough it might just work - will test and if works as expected you got yourself a correct answer tick from me

Comment: had a little issue at first with it not showing up until i made a change in one of the values - then with initializing with an empty collection on some cases - once i got it figured out how to properly initialize it to a correct value worked like a charm - thanks

Comment: An upvote would also be appreciated :).  That is, if my answer helped.  Remember, checkmark for the answer, and an upvote for something that is especially helpful.  You can do both.